# Django Collectstatic command Changed something

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles, django-static

So I've never deployed a Django app and I'm trying to get up to speed on the whole thing. I ran the collectstatic command and now non of my static files will render. When I run the findstatic command I receive an exception that says:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The storage backend of the staticfiles finder     <class 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder'> doesn't have a valid location.
```

My template renders just find but I can't seem to figure out why the css file is not being found. Highlight from my settings module:

```
settings/
    base.py
    devel.py
    prod.py
```

base.py

```
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
PROJECT_ROOT = cwd[:-9] # chop off "settings/"

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
]

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),
]
```

devl.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static")
```

site_base.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/site_base.css" />
```

Would appreciate your help because Im stumped.

Comment: Got a [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) setting?

Comment: yes. static_root setting updated and included above.

Comment: More importantly, with that finder, do you have a [DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders) setting?

Comment: Looks like the default for that is `django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage`. The loader looks for `storage.base_location`, and the default value of that on `FileSystemStorage` is `MEDIA_ROOT`. You could try pointing `MEDIA_ROOT` at your static files.

Comment: This may all be a red herring, though, as I think `FileSystemFinder` and `AppDirectoriesFinder` should find your static files even if the third one fails. What is the path from your PROJECT_ROOT to your `site_base.css`, by the way?

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. The path from the site root to the site_base.css is   /tulsa/static/css/site_base.css

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

It turned out to be a missing context processor.  To get your STATIC_URL setting inside a template, you have to register the `staticfiles` context processor:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    ...
]
```

**First stab:**

It looks like you'll need to add that dir to your list of static sources (re: a comment above):

```
# list of input paths for collectstatic
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "tulsa", "static"),

    # you'll want to remove this path:
    #os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static"),
]

# output path for collectstatic
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "site_media", "static")
```

Comment: When you view source on the page, what is output for {{ STATIC_URL }}?

Comment: "<link href="css/site_base.css" rel="stylesheet">" there is also the "page not found" template in the source view as a dropdown menu under this line.

Comment: So that's the problem - STATIC_URL is not in your context. Could you post the View code?

Comment: AH - have you registered the [staticfiles context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-static)?

Comment: Ok, so I updated the template context processor with "django.core.context_processors.static"and the html view source now reads <link href="/site_media/static/css/site_base.css" rel="stylesheet">
A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.
</link>

Comment: Good -- it looks like your static files are in the right place now. This will be a new error. If you set `DEBUG=True`, you should get a nice error page with a stack trace.

Comment: thanks so much for hanging in there with me on this. Im currently receiving this exception in the terminal: "ImproperlyConfigured: The storage backend of the staticfiles finder <class 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder'> doesn't have a valid location."

Comment: My third comment on your original post should lead you in the right direction for that problem, but keep in mind `collectstatic` is not required at all when using `runserver`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still having trouble getting the css working. I'm receiving 404 error when trying to load static urls directly.